# DataReader performance issue, odd behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am facing similar issue as [Big Performance Problems With Oracle DataReader in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141175/big-performance-problems-with-oracle-datareader-in-net). My Stored Procedure is using union all on two queries (Each of them are using some joins). In all, the SP returns some 20K records in 10 seconds. Which looks okay.

But, I am facing issues on application side where the dataReader.Read() takes around four minutes to just fetch these data. Below is the code I am currently using:

```
        List<int> ordinalIndexes = new List<int>();

        foreach (string headerName in headerColumnMapping.Keys)
            ordinalIndexes.Add(dataReader.GetOrdinal(headerColumnMapping[headerName].ToString()));

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            foreach (var ordinalIndex in ordinalIndexes)
                csvString.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"{1}", dataReader[ordinalIndex].ToString().Trim(), separator);
        }
```

I've observed that there are many chunks in dataReader.Read() which are processed quiet easily (less than a milliseconds). But, there are many more which take 10-35 seconds (for one single read).

I tried:

1. Optimizing SP. Not sure if this SP can be optimized more?
2. Tried implementing MARS (as suggested in [Really odd DataReader performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158072/really-odd-datareader-performance-issue)). But it did not work for me.

Any suggestion on this is highly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved by optimizing the stored procedure. I added few indexes (based on the queries in the SP) and the overall performance was improved to a great extent.

Thanks for @Steve for your inputs on application level changes. Although, for my case, DB performance was the real culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot test with your data, but some optimizations could be added to your loop.
For example do not format each single field but format a whole row.

You can try to adapt this code to your data

```
string separator = ";";
int pos = 0;
string format = "";

// Prepare the format mask for the whole records
foreach (string headerName in headerColumnMapping)
{
    format += "\"{" + pos  + "}\"" + separator;
    pos++;
}
// Remove the last separator and add a newline
format = format.Substring(0, format.Length - 1) + "\r\n";

// Create the array of the field positions
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount);

// Set an initial capacity for the string builder to 10MB
// Of course this could be a waste of memory if you plan to retrieve
// small amounts of data.
StringBuilder csvString = new StringBuilder(1024*1024*10);

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    var x = dataReader as IDataRecord;

    // Create the array of the field values
    var k = range.Select(r => x[r].ToString()).ToArray();

    // Append the whole line
    csvString.AppendFormat(format, k);  
}
```

The code above retrieves all fields from the datareader. If you want to retrieve only some fields mapped through your *ordinalIndexes* list then just remove the creation of the range and use your current code to prepare the list of integers to retrieve. Then replace *range.Select* with  *ordinalIndexes.Select*

Another little thing but with a lot of payout is to define the capacity of the StringBuilder in particular if you expect to retrieve a lot of data. If you define immediately a large enough initial capacity you avoid reallocation of memory when the buffer fills.

However if you are trying to export a CSV file I would suggest to look at some library that specializes in creating CSV files. Probably you could check them if you have better performances.

Comment: Let me try to implement above suggestion. Hope to see some improvement in performance.

Comment: Although, I'm concerned about the odd behavior of datareader. It basically takes longer time for many subsequent reads.

Comment: I tried above script although, it did not help much in improving the performance. Please note, I am concerned about the odd behavior of datareader. It basically takes longer time for many subsequent reads